# Copying data to clipboard manager Ditto

Tags: python, clipboard, ditto

I refused to ask a question here but I just can't find a solution.

I use Ditto as my fav clipboard manager, when I copy data there I can access it via assigned keys on my keyboard. This is very handy. I need to copy values from cells in Excel, so far I've tried many solutions but each one has the same outcome, mainly (tkinter, pyperclip, pandas, os, pynput) gives me an output as a last copied variable (or string) under first position in Ditto. If I copy value 'a' then 'b' it gives me 'b' or I gain access to whole copied content it doesnt distinguish. The closest solution is in this code below, close but it is still whole content in one clip under one key.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from pyperclip import *

wb = load_workbook(filename='C:/Users/Robert/Desktop/dane.xlsx')
ws = wb['Sheet']
column = ws['B']


list = ''
for x in range(len(column)) :
    a = ''
    if column[x].value is None:
         column[x].value = a


    list = list + str(column[x].value) + '\n'

copy(list)
```

I need every single string (cell.value) under different slot in Ditto. This gives me all values in one (first) slot.

Thanks in advance, it is fourth day in a row and I am close to jump from my balcony...

Answer (score 0):

Lately I came across a solution. 
Ditto requires delay, at least 500ms to copy items separately.

```
    for i in arr:
        pyperclip.copy(i)
        time.sleep(.6)
```